# Sending emails Via Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have been given the task of creating a spread sheet that will take in some cell phone records information. We have reports that run everyday to see data usage by each phone(they are exported as a CSV). we need a way to automate the sending of emails(text messages via email) based on if a cell value is true. currently the spread sheet looks like this (Cell are expressedby || )

**|Wireless Number| User_name| Billing Cycle Date| Cost Center| Data_Usage| 90%| 100| email Address| 90% message| 100% message|**

I am looking for some VBA code that will run when a marco is called via a button or keyboard short cut that will take in the email address and send a message that is in the 90% o 100% of data use cell.
any advice would be nice.

Comment: This scope of question is off-topic for SO. Questions need to be about a **specific** programming problem. E.G. "How do I Create an email using VBA?". "How do I write a *program to do xyz*" is far too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this question is off-topic (see my comment).

What you need to do is break your problem down int concrete steps.

E.G.

1) Pass text values to variables
2) Check those variables to see if they meet your filtering requirements (90% <= Cell USage <= 100%)
3) Open Outlook
4) Create a new email object
5) Populate the email with Address and the email body of text
6) Send the email

Each of those would make a Question by themselves (possibly more than 1). Break the problem down. Write what you know how to do. When you get to the point in your code where you can't do the next step, then ask a question about it on SO.